# How to write test to handle custom exceptions in clojure

Tags: unit-testing, exception, clojure

How do we write test case in clojure to test a custom exception raised by `(Exception. "MyCustomException")`

I tried `(is (thrown? (Exception. "MyCustomException") (method-name param)))`
But this does not work.

PS: I am new to clojure

Comment: What does `method-name` do? Assuming it throws Exception your test would need a try/catch. You can then look into the exception caught and see if it's what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the instance? method to check if the Exception type is derived => http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/instance_q

```
(defrecord ExampleExceptionClass [x])

(try
  ;; do something here
  (catch Exception ex
    (instance? ExampleExceptionClass ex)))
```